# Kendo UI Web using multiselect in a grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to use the Kendo UI Grid to display and edit a multi-valued property. I am not using the Jsp or the ASP.NET wrapper to do so. I am facing a couple of problems with this. First of all, I am not able to see the data populated from the server in the grid under the grid column. Also, I am trying to use a normal multi-select control (HTML) for use as the custom editor. The data populated is in the json format and returns an array of hashes for the multivalued property e.g.
If the property is libraries the json being fetched is "libraries" : [{id:1, name:"name1"}, {id:2, name: "name2"}]

How do I customize the display of this property to show comma separated names in the grid. Also, how do I use a select box as the editor and bind it to the data already selected?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I am understanding correctly, it sounds like you have a Nested Json object inside some json. If you are using stock Kendo ui datasource, you will not be able to access it as it does not allow for nested objects.

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/data-source/dealing-with-complex-json-crud.aspx#06BfDnAGS0egdLumlK9Zdg

You could use a $.ajax call to pull in your json. eval(data) to turn it into an object, at that time you could go in, flatten that particular part of the json to be a string and then pass that flat array into the datasource.

V/R